# maven keep trying to connect to an non-exist intranet repo site

Tags: java, maven, repository

I ran maven with a modified settings.xml here is part of it:

```
  <mirrors>
 <!--
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>Nexus Repository Manager.</name>
  <url>http://my.intra.repo.site:8081/nexus/public/</url>
</mirror>
-->
```

Actually after I commented out the above mirror (http://my.intra.repo.site:8081/nexus/public/), maven tries to connect some other url http://xyz.repo.site (http://xyz.repo.site was the first I used but I removed it later since it's discommisioned). A couple of notes:

1. I didn't run the wrong settings.xml - if I changed the mirror to something else, it's reflected in the log;
2. I vaguely recalled that the repo url should be put in the profile, not in mirror tag, am I wrong about it?

Thanks,
John

Comment: I would include, if not the entire settings.xml, at least the interesting parts of it, here. And, just to have something constructive to say here, did you try changing something else in that xml file to verify that you are actually reading the settings.xml?

Comment: thanks mattias for the suggestion, I edited the post per the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the mystery is resolved. I looked though the project and found in the pom.xml in its root, the old url http://xyz.repo.site is inside the tag pluginRepository, I didn't notice it  thus it's never updated. I supposed this one takes over if no explicit repo is set in the settings.xml. My bad.